# What is the correct phrase for "speaks well to the"

Tags: phrases, expressions

For example, if I want to say something like "The fact that the space ship survived the meteor impact speaks well to its reliability."  What is the accepted/standard phrase for 'speaks well to'.  I am fairly sure that 'speaks well to' is not correct and/or standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression 'speak well of' is idiomatic:

> **speak well of / for**
>
> to show that something is correct or effective
>
> *The lower crime rate speaks well for the police department’s new strategy.*

{[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/speak-well-for-of)}

Of course, this has the alternative meaning 'praise'.

.............................

Alternatively, 'testify well to' may be used:

> *The difficulties Leibniz and Varignon found in giving an analytic form*
>   *to dynamics testify well to the fact that their effort was not*
>   *trivial.*

{[The Development of Newtonian Calculus in Britain, 1700-1800](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nIKVQCeI1FUC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22testify+well+to%22&source=bl&ots=ZbdG1tjJV6&sig=UVhudpnoR7Ze-7MGVv7M-TQRibo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO76HZoojZAhXqC8AKHci3CMgQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22testify%20well%20to%22&f=false)}

> **testify to**
>
> testify 2 to provide evidence that something exists or is true
>
> testify to: *These ruins testify to the existence of Roman
>   occupation.*

{[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/testify)}

Comment: You can also say "The fact that the space ship survived the meteor impact **is a testament to** its reliability."

Comment: 'Well for' does not sound idiomatic to my British English ear. I suggest you prefer 'well of' If your readership will extend beyond North America. That should sound right for both BrE and AmE.

Comment: I've heard *speaks to* here and there, and particularly examples like *[to the credibility of](https://ludwig.guru/s/speaks+to+the+credibility)*.